# Regular expression to find all the dots in a string and replace with '_'

Tags: regex, puppet

I am working in puppet. Can somebody help in replacing all the dots in a string with underscore--

```
$version_name =a.b.c.d.f
$file = regsubst($version_name,'\.','_')
```

Something like this. Which will provide output as --
a_b_c_d_f

Comment: use `g` or `global` flag

Answer (score 1):

Use the regsubst [global replacement flag](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#regsubst) as your fourth parameter. You can also avoid escapes if you put the period into a character class. For example:

```
$ puppet apply -e '$version_name = "a.b.c.d.f"
                   notice regsubst($version_name, "[.]", "_", "G")'
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): a_b_c_d_f
```